# How to validate my form in Zend Framework 2 and Doctrine?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2, zend-form

so i have some entities and i want to validate my forms, i use **Zend Framework 2** and **Doctrine Orm**, **Update Thanks to Notuser** : now i get this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::initForm() in C:\wamp2\www\test\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\BlogController.php
```

**this is my model.config.php :**

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        'application_entities' => array(
            'class' =>'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Application/Entity')
        ),
        'application_forms' => array(
                'class' =>'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Application/Form')
        ),
        'application_inputs_filters' => array(
                'class' =>'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Application/InputFilter')
        ),

        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                'Application\Entity' => 'application_entities',
                'Application\Form'   => 'application_forms',
                'Application\InputFilter'    => 'application_inputs_filters'
            )
        )
    )
),
```

**and this my controller :**

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Application\Entity\Article;
use Application\Entity\Image;
use Application\Form\ArticleForm;

class BlogController extends AbstractActionController
 {
   protected $_objectManager;

public function addAction()
{       
    $form = $this->getServiceLocator('Application\Form\ArticleForm');
    $form->initForm();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form->setData($request->getPost());

    $article = new Article();
    if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) 
        {
            $file = $this->params()->fromFiles('url');

            $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
            $adapter->setDestination('public/upload');
            if($adapter->receive($file['name'])){


                $article->setTitle($this->getRequest()->getPost('title'));
                $article->setDate(new \DateTime($this->getRequest()->getPost('date')));
                $article->setContent($this->getRequest()->getPost('content'));
                $article->setPublication($this->getRequest()->getPost('publication'));
                $image = new Image();
                $image->setUrl($file['name']);
                $image->setAlt($this->getRequest()->getPost('alt'));
                $article->setImage($image);

                $this->getObjectManager()->persist($article);
                $this->getObjectManager()->flush();
                $newId = $article->getId();

                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('blog');
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('user');
    }
    return new ViewModel(array('article' => $article));
}
```

**And this is my ArticleForm :**

```
class ArticleForm extends Form {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct('UserEntry');

    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    $this->setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    $this->setAttribute('class', 'contact_form');
}

/**
 *
 */
public function initForm()
{
    $this->addFormFields(); //function where we added all fields

    $articleInputFilter = new ArticleInputFilter();
    $this->setInputFilter($articleInputFilter->getInputFilter()); //Asign input Filter to form
}

/**
 *
 */
protected function addFormFields()
{
    $this->addSubmit();
    $this->addTitle();
    $this->addContent();
    $this->addDate();
    $this->addPublication();
    $this->addImage();
}

/**
 *
 */
protected function addTitle()
{
    $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'title',
            'attributes' => array(
                    'type' => 'text',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                    'label' => _('Title')
            ),
    ));
}

/**
 *
 */
protected function addContent()
{
    $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'content',
            'attributes' => array(
                    'type' => 'text',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                    'label' => _('Content')
            ),
    ));
}

/**
 *
 */
protected function addDate()
{
    $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'date',
            'attributes' => array(
                    'type' => 'date',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                    'label' => _('Date'),
                    'id'    => 'datepicker',
            ),
    ));
}

/**
 *
 */
protected function addPublication()
{
    $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'publication',
            'attributes' => array(
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                    'label' => _('Publication'),
                    'use_hidden_element' => true,
                    'checked_value' => 1,
                    'unchecked_value' => 'no',
            ),
    ));
}

/**
 *
 */
protected function addImage()
{
    $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'Image',
            'attributes' => array(
                    'type' => new ImageForm(),
            ),
            'options' => array(
                    'label' => _('Image')
            ),
    ));
}

/**
 *
 */
protected function addSubmit()
{
    $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                    'type' => 'submit',
                    'value' => _('Add'),
                    'class' => 'submit',
            ),
    ));
}
}
```

**Finally this is my ArticleInputFilter :**

```
class ArticleInputFilter extends InputFilter implements InputFilterAwareInterface 
  {
/**
 * @var string
 */
public $title;

/**
 * @var int
 */
public $image;

/**
 * @var string
 */
public $content;

/**
 * @var Date
 */
public $date;

/**
 * @var Boolean
 */
public $publication;

/**
 * @param $data
 */
public function exchangeArray($data)
{
    $this->title     = (isset($data['title']))     ? $data['title']     : $this->title;
    $this->image     = (isset($data['image']))     ? $data['image']     :  $this->image;
    $this->content     = (isset($data['content']))     ? $data['content']     : $this->content;
    $this->publication   = (isset($data['publication']))       ? $data['publication']   :  $this->publication;
    $this->date      = (isset($data['date']))      ? $data['date']  :  $this->date;
}

/**
 * @param InputFilterInterface $inputFilter
 * @return void|InputFilterAwareInterface
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
{
    throw new \Exception("Not used");
}

/**
 * @return InputFilter|InputFilterInterface
 */
public function getInputFilter()
{
    if (!$this->inputFilter) {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
        $factory     = new InputFactory();

        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name'     => 'title',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                        array(
                                'name'    => 'StringLength',
                                'options' => array(
                                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                        'min'      => 6,
                                        'max'      => 100,
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
        )));

        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name'     => 'content',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  => array(
                        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                        array(
                                'name'    => 'StringLength',
                                'options' => array(
                                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                        'min'      => 10,
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
        )));

        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name'     => 'publication',
                'required' => false,
        )));

        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name'     => 'date',
                'required' => true,
        )));

        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name'     => 'image',
                'required' => true,
        )));

        $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
    }

    return $this->inputFilter;
}
  }
```

**That it** i write my hole code except my **ImageForm** and **ImageInputFilter**, So please if someone has any idea how to do that i will be very appreciative ;)

Comment: First off: it's good that you try to learn. But as doing so, reading the [official Documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org) is a must-to-do for every beginner. Your questions strongly indicate that you're trying to go from 0 to 100 in no time. That won't work. Take the time to read yourself through the QuickStart and then for specific questions go to specific sections of the Documentation. Sometimes it's good to jump in the water tryint to learn to swim, but don't do so in the middle of an Ocean. Find yourself a small Pond first...

Answer (score 2):

In controller

```
$form = $this->getServiceLocator('Application\Form\BlogForm");//don't forger to add Application\Form\BlogForm to module.config.php and check your namespace
        $form->initForm();//explained further

        /** @var \Zend\Http\Request $request */
        $request = $this->getRequest();//whole request fo @var for further using
        if ($request->isPost()) { //there is something in post
            $form->setData($request->getPost()); //data from post is added for further validation
            if ($form->isValid()) { //Form is Valid lets save form
                $files = $request->getFiles()->toArray(); //array witch files use var_dump($files);die; to show structure

                $article = new Article();
                $article->setTitle($request->getPost('title'));
                ...
                if(!empty($files)&&$files['image']['error']==0) {
                    $article->setImage($functionToCreateImageEntityFromFile(($files['image']));
                }
                ...
                $this->getObjectManager()->persist($article);
                $this->getObjectManager()->flush();
                $newId = $article->getId();

                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('blog');
            }
            //form is not valid so you can display form with Errors
        } //there is no post so you can display clean form
```

Next let's take form:
(it's my proposal)

```
namespace Application\Form; //check your namespace

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Application\InputFilter\BlogInputFilter; //check your namespace

class BlogForm extends Form {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('UserEntry');

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function initForm()
    {
        $this->addFormFields(); //function where we added all fields

        $blogInputFilter = new BlogInputFilter(); //Input Filter for Validation
        $this->setInputFilter($BlogInputFilter->getInputFilter()); //Asign input Filter to form
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    protected function addFormFields()
    {
            $this->addSubmit();
            $this->addTitle();
            $this->addImage();
            ...//add more here
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    protected function addTitle()
    {
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'title',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'id' => 'title',
                'class' => 'text'
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => _('Title') //it's only for multilang you can put here any string
            ),
        ));
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    protected function addImage()
    {
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'image',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'file',
                'id' => 'image'
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => _('Image'),
            ),
        ));
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    protected function addSubmit()
    {
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'value' => _('Save'),
                'class' => 're',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

Now its Time for InputFilter

```
namespace Application\InputFilter;//check your namespace

use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

class BlogInputFilter implements InputFilterAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $image;

    //add all fields

    /**
     * @param $data
     */
    public function exchangeArray($data)
    {
        $this->title     = (isset($data['title']))     ? $data['title']     : $this->title;
        $this->image = (isset($data['image'])) ? $data['image'] :  $this->image;
        //add fields
    }

    /**
     * @param InputFilterInterface $inputFilter
     * @return void|InputFilterAwareInterface
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
    {
        throw new \Exception("Not used");
    }

    /**
     * @return InputFilter|InputFilterInterface
     */
    public function getInputFilter()
    {
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory     = new InputFactory();

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name'     => 'title',
                'required' => true,//required field
                'filters'  => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name'    => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min'      => 1,
                            'max'      => 100,//limit from 1 to 100 chars
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )));

            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;
    }
}
```

to read:

Forms:  http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#factory-backed-form-extension

ImputFilter: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html

File upload: Can't find good tutorial

module.config.php should have key like this:

```
 'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Form\ArticleForm' => 'Application\Form\ArticleForm',
    ),
),
```

There is no need to add Application\Form\ArticleForm to use becouse you use ServiceLocator

Comment: Thanks so much @Notuser i am really appreciate your reply, now i have a problem in my controller i get an error, i will update my post to see my problem.

Comment: @Mohammadov betwen this lines $form = $this->getServiceLocator('Application\Form\ArticleForm');
    $form->initForm(); add: var_dump($form); probably you did not added form to module.config.php (show me this file)

Comment: ok but i added my Form to the module.config.php, just see my update i wrote it, ok i will upload it for you.

Comment: @Mohammadov you don't added lines for service_manager to your module.config.php look at my answer  'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Form\ArticleForm' => 'Application\Form\ArticleForm',
    ),
),

Comment: i added but i still get the same error !! this is my module.config.php  you can take a look in it : https://www.mediafire.com/?c1bfm61fm4kvg2n

Comment: @Mohammadov ok before initForm add var_dump($form);die; and paste output

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

```
$form = $this->getServiceLocator('Application\Form\ArticleForm');
$form->initForm();
```

It should be:

```
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Form\ArticleForm');
$form->initForm();
```

The way you have written it, the bracket contents are ignored and it becomes:

```
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()
```

which is why you get an "undefined method: ServiceManager::initForm()" error when you call initForm().